# can I modify the generated getter/setter template?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'd like to make all method parameters final by default, can I modify the template somewhere so that all generated methods also have parameters marked as final?

Answer (score 4):

Settings -> Code Style -> Java -> Code Generation tab and check `Make generated parameters final`.